# Binary search return first occurrence of n

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I have implemented the following binary search method for finding the position of `n` in a sorted array.

```
Array.prototype.binarySearch = function(n) {
    var o = 0;
    var i = this.length;

    while(i) {
        i >>= 1;
        if(n == this[i+o]) return i+o;
        else if(n > this[i+o]) o += i+1;
    }

    return -1;
};
```

However, if there are multiple occurrences of `n`, it will return an arbitrary index instead of the first occurrence.
How can I adjust my implementation to return the first occurrence of `n` instead?

Comment: Wiki describing the alogrithm for this in a language agnostic way: [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure_for_finding_the_leftmost_element)